# How can I make goog.Timer be more precise?

Tags: timer, google-closure, google-closure-library

I made a `goog.Timer` object (http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_Timer.html) with `new goog.Timer(1)` to run a function every millisecond via listening to the tick event. However, the function seemed to be running every 100 milliseconds instead.

I hypothesized that my function was taking a while to run (and javascript is single-threaded of course), so it took a while to get to the next round. Hence, I set the interval for the timer to 100, and it reliably ran every 1/10 of a second.

Does The Google Closure library have a more reliable timer that only runs a function precisely at the interval? If there is not enough time to run a function in one cycle, I am fine with canceling the previous call and running it the next time a tick is dispatched.

Comment: `goog.Timer` wraps the native `setInterval`, which itself is probably not fast enough to run your function in 1 ms.  Are you sure you need that much granularity?  1ms polling is brutal.  Can you not use `goog.events.listen` and `dispatchEvent`?

Comment: Thanks, I don't need 1ms granularity. 20-100ms would be nice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicholas Zakas wrote up a nice summary of ***[Timer resolution in browsers](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/)*** on his blog. As Nicholas pointed out, the [HTML5 timers specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) (as of August 2, 2012) dictates that the minimum interval for `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` is 4 milliseconds.

I wrote the following demo application to test the minimum interval delay for `goog.Timer`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>goog.Timer Test</title>
  <script src="../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>goog.Timer Test</h1>

<div id="mainContent"></div>

<script>
  goog.require('goog.Timer');
</script>
<script>
  var tickCount = 0;
  var timer = new goog.Timer(1);
  var mainDiv = document.querySelector('#mainContent');

  /**
   * Tick callback.
   */
  var tickCounter = function() {
    tickCount++;
    if (tickCount % 1000 === 0) {
      var timeElapsed = goog.now() - startTime;
      mainDiv.innerHTML = 'goog.Timer tick events: ' + tickCount +
          '<br>actual elapsed milliseconds: ' + timeElapsed +
          '<br>milliseconds per goog.Timer tick: ' + timeElapsed/tickCount;
    }
  };

  startTime = goog.now();
  timer.start();
  goog.events.listen(timer, goog.Timer.TICK, tickCounter);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this program in Chrome version 21 consistently shows approximately 4.2 milliseconds per `goog.Timer` tick event, which is very close to the minimum allowable browser timer resolution of 4 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about goog timers, but this worked in my emulator. It stopped 3 milliseconds after I told it to though.

```
public Timer gameTimer;
int i = 1;
TextView TVsource;//You still have to assign this to a layout view in onCreate

public void runTimer() {

    gameTimer = new Timer();
    gameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (i < 5000) {
                TimerMethod();
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1);
}

public void TimerMethod() {
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        i++;
        TVsource.setText("its " + i);
    }
};
```

P.S. I just realized this is a javascript question, but what the hell? Try it.